# Dynamically listen for v-on on vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a filter returning plain HTML in vuejs. And in this HTML there is a `v-on` tag.
How can I make vuejs to parse again HTML to detect new content/events listeners/ etc. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: In Vue 1.0, if you know what components you need to instantiate (versus compiling random HTML), you can also use the `parent` argument on View Model instantiation: http://vuejs.org/api/#parent

---

You will need to manually compile that HTML within the View Model using `$compile` (currently undocumented). See this discussion for more information:

https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/77